# Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL input type ("TypeService") for the "servicesType". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator

Tags: graphql, nestjs, prisma-graphql

```
import { ObjectType, Field, Int, ID } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { TypeService } from 'src/type-services/entities/type-service.entity';

@ObjectType()
export class Schedule {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id?: string;

  @Field(() => Date)
  date: string | Date;

  @Field(() => String)
  userID: string;

  @Field(() => [TypeService])
  servicesType?: TypeService[];
}


import { InputType, Int, Field, ID } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { TypeService } from 'src/type-services/entities/type-service.entity';

@InputType()
export class CreateScheduleInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  userID: string | null;

  @Field()
  date: Date;

  @Field(() => [TypeService])
  servicesType?: TypeService[];
}
```

Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL input type ("TypeService") for the "servicesType". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that `TypeService` is either annotated with `@ObjectType()` or not annotated at all as it is the most likely reason for the error.

The issue is that you are using a non-InputType (`TypeService`) as a property of an InputType (`CreateScheduleInput`), and nested fields of an InputType must be InputTypes as well.

The solution would be to define an InputType for the `TypeService` (such as `CreateTypeServiceInput`) which would be annotated with `@InputType()`.